# How to do mathematical operations in base other than 10?

Tags: c, algorithm

I want to convert binary number to octal directly without converting into base 10, I found some solutions at math.stackexchange.com but they need the operations to be done in that base itself(which is not 10), so is there a way or algorithm to  do operations in base other than 10?
I need to know how to convert a number from any base to any base.

Comment: It would actually be more difficult to convert to base 10 first.

Comment: I suspect you've correctly understood the problem and the solutions you've found. Most operations mathematics is concerned with aren't done in base 10, or any base for that matter - the concept of a base doesn't even enter the picture because you work with platonic numbers, not on their representation in some alphabet.

Comment: Close Voters: Though this question might be considered by some as 'off topic' (I don't, it's an algorithm that can be written in any programming langauge) - I really see no base for the claim it is 'too broad' - the question is very specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting binary to octal (and vice-versa)  is fairly easy because 2^3=8.

This means you only need to go from least significant bits to most significant bits, and 'translate' each group of 3 bits to its respective number.

**Example:**

101 100 110:

```
110 -> 6
100 -> 4
101 -> 5
```

Translation to octal is now simply 546.

Comment: How about other bases? like from base 3 to base 7?

Comment: @user3340031 That's done completely differently and is a different question.

Comment: If you need to work on more bases, just convert it back to 10 and then print as n-base number. That would be the easiest solution.

Comment: Sorry ill edit the question , as I already mentioned in the question , I dun wanna convert the number to base 10

Comment: @user3340031 if the base a power of 2, then it's easy enough, but if it isn't then you're better off converting to 10 first.

Comment: @user3340031 What's the motivation behind it? It will require doing arithmetics (such as additions, multiply,...) in non-standard bases. These ops are not implemented, and you will have to customly create them. It will most likely also be MUCH slower than the alternative for any base which are not power of each other.

Comment: @amit I'll leave it here then , I was given that problem as a homework and I was thinking if it was possible to write a function that can convert any base to any base (Think that's just a dream! :P), just like `int(str,base)` in python which converts any base to base 10 atleast

Answer (score 1):

You just have to take each set of 3 digits and convert them to octal starting from the least significant bit:

```
010110111011110 (base 2)

010 110 111 011 110
 2   6   7   3   6  (base 8)
```